# Reading multiple XML files freezes applicaton

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write an application for a game called Eve Online, where people mine planets for product. The app is basically training for me, and is supposed to tell people when their operations expire, so they can reset. Some players have 30 characters, with 120 planets and over 200 timed operations.

I have written code to store the characters in an `SQLite` db, then I'm pulling each characters 2 verification codes and return their equipment. This info is stored in 2 separate XML documents. One with the planets, and another for each planets with the equipment on it. I have tried to solve getting it all in the following way:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace PITimer
{
class GetPlanets
{
    private long KeyID, CharacterID;
    private string VCode;
    string CharName;
    public List<long> planets = new List<long>();
    public List<string> planetNames = new List<string>();
    public List<AllInfo> allInfo = new List<AllInfo>();

    public GetPlanets(long KeyID, long CharacterID, string VCode, string CharName)
    {
        this.KeyID = KeyID;
        this.CharacterID = CharacterID;
        this.VCode = VCode;
        this.CharName = CharName;
    }

    public async Task PullPlanets()
    {
        XmlReader lesern = XmlReader.Create("https://api.eveonline.com/char/PlanetaryColonies.xml.aspx?keyID=" + KeyID + "&vCode=" + VCode + "&characterID=" + CharacterID);

        while (lesern.Read())
        {
            long planet = 000000;
            string planetName;
            planet = Convert.ToInt64(lesern.GetAttribute("planetID"));
            planetName = lesern.GetAttribute("planetName");

            if ((planet != 000000) && (planetName != null))
            {
                planets.Add(planet);
                planetNames.Add(planetName);
                await GetExpirationTimes(planet, planetName);

            }
        }
    }



    public async Task GetExpirationTimes(long planetID, string planetName)
    {
        string planet = planetID.ToString();
        XmlReader lesern = XmlReader.Create("https://api.eveonline.com/char/PlanetaryPins.xml.aspx?keyID=" + KeyID + "&vCode=" + VCode + "&characterID=" + CharacterID + "&planetID=" + planet);


        while (lesern.Read())
        {
            string expTime;
            expTime = lesern.GetAttribute("expiryTime");

            if ((expTime != null) && (expTime != "0001-01-01 00:00:00"))
            {
                allInfo.Add(new AllInfo(CharName, planetName, Convert.ToDateTime(expTime)));

            }
        }
    }


    public List<long> ReturnPlanets()
    {
        PullPlanets();
        return planets;
    }

    public List<string> ReturnNames()
    {
        return planetNames;
    }

    public List<AllInfo> ReturnAllInfo()
    {
        return allInfo;
    }

}
```

}

This does work and it returns the data, which I run into a `ListView` on Xamarin Android. My problem is that it freezes the system when it runs. I am testing with 2 characters, and the UI is sometimes frozen for several seconds. Other times it runs fine. But with 30 characters I am going to run into trouble.

I have tried solving this with async and task in every configuration I have been able to imagine. Its still either slow or not working at all. How do I set this up in a way that will work in an app?

Its also running a lighter check in a background service, which it does, but I fear I will really strain the system.

The planet XML can be seen here: https://api.eveonline.com/char/PlanetaryColonies.xml.aspx?keyID=3060230&vCode=1ft0nDTRaXgVM6r0co9QhJUq3tC5hYErfBFrt7Skilk4181krBiIRVhshH1TzkDP&characterID=94304895

I pull the planet ID and from that run this XML:

https://api.eveonline.com/char//PlanetaryPins.xml.aspx?keyID=3060230&vCode=1ft0nDTRaXgVM6r0co9QhJUq3tC5hYErfBFrt7Skilk4181krBiIRVhshH1TzkDP&characterID=94304895&planetID=40175117

I have used `XMLDoc` before, but thought reader would be better and faster for this.

Comment: Don't do I/O on the UI thread. Problem solved!

Comment: That almost sounds to good to be true. Could you elaborate a little, though? Im not very good, as im sure you can see from both my code and my question.

Comment: Spawn a thread to do all this reading and then return to the UI thread. Once your worker thread finishes, it can notify the UI thread with the data using `Invoke()`. Two extra points that spring at me: use multiple connections in parallel to download (3 connections means you get the data 3 times faster), and `000000` is not what you think it is.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot. So from my Fragment i could do something like 
GetPlanet = new GetPlanets(KeyIDOut, CharIDOut, VCodeOut, navnOut);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (o => GetPlanet.PullPlanets()); 
newInfo = GetPlanet.ReturnAllInfo();
allInfo.AddRange(newInfo);
I have tried this a million times now, and am all confused. Sorry about that. 
I have no idea how to open more connections, but really appreciate the advice and will check it out. Please write an answer, so I can mark it as answered.

Comment: Spawning another thread would keep your UI responsive, but as another note, simply marking a method with `async` doesn't make it run asynchronously. You might take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) if you're interested in getting started with asynchronous code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But the problem is the UI alone, then? Running an XmlReader like this is legit?

Comment: From what you've described, that would be my guess. Fetching each of the player's planets and every operation on those planets is potentially costly, time-wise. As long as you keep updating the `ListView` as you gather the information, it should be more seamless by running in the background.

Comment: Hello again! Just wanted to tell you that your advice solved all my troubles - and made the app feel and look a lot better. Thanks a lot! I deeply underestimated the power of threading.